# php sleep() doesn´t work step by step

Tags: php, sleep

Having the following code:

```
echo '<br />Testing sleep().<br />';
$i = 0;
while(true) {
    sleep(2);
    echo '1 '.$i.'<br />';
    if ($i++ > 3) {
    break;
    }
}
```

I have different results in two different servers:
Server 1: PHP 7.0.25 :: Linux/Apache 2.X :: http://www.kobily.com/test_sleep.php
Server 2: PHP 7.0.16 :: Linux/Apache 2.X :: http://m.ubimovi.com/test_sleep.php

In the first server everything work's Ok, the sleep() instruction holds every step for 2 seconds and then displays every line.
In the second server it waits for 6 seconds, and then it displays the complete text.
flush(), ob_start(), ob_flush(), ob_end_flush(), ob_get_level(), set_time_limit(0), ob_implicit_flush(true), ob_get_contents(), ob_end_clean(), session_write_close(), have already been used without having a different result.
Is there a way to identify the parameter to modify in order to have the same behaviour as in Server 1?

Comment: you mean flushing the output?

Comment: Its a buffer output setting somewhere. Some php servers hold onto more data before pushing to the web browser... while others do it less.

Comment: The PHP script runs the same way on both servers. The web server and/or the PHP interpreter and/or a proxy in front of the web server buffers the output. There are ways to improve the result but there is no universal solution (to not say there is not a complete solution for this.) Oh, and your code doesn't attempt to [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) the interpreter's buffer in any way. You are lucky it works as you expect on one of the servers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [echo from php "as it goes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123732/echo-from-php-as-it-goes)

Comment: flush(), ob_start(), ob_flush(), ob_end_flush(), ob_get_level(), set_time_limit(0), ob_implicit_flush(true), ob_get_contents(), ob_end_clean(), session_write_close(), have already been used without having a different result.

Comment: About Possible duplicate: I don´t see it as solved in "echo from php "as it goes". I tried to add my question there but I received a message saying that it does not answer the question and I must raise a new one.
My intention is to find, at least one solution to this problem. I can include here the differences in the php.ini files and anything else needed.
Anybody willing to take he callenge?